# IMAP "Over Quota" specific scripting

Tags: java, python, protocols, imap, quota

I realize there are a number of libraries to access IMAP, from Java, Python, etc.  But what I want to do is very specific, and is counter to most imap examples.

The easy parts:

- Given an IMAP server, login, and specific folder name
- Nuke all messages in that folder  (Or Nuke the folder, if that's easier or more efficient?)

The atypical parts:

- Do an expunge after every N deletes
- Include some retry and batch size logic so that busy servers - even deleting and expunging 100 messages per session would be a help.
- DON'T download all the headers!

That last point is a problem.  Every email client I've tried chokes on downloading the 20,000 email headers - which I don't need to see.

With POP3 scripting I've just given sequential IDs, 1, 2, 3 ...

But every IMAP example I've seen appears to use some field that it got from the headers.  So maybe deleting IMAP messages *requires* an ID that you can't guess at?  (and can only get by doing a query?)

If I did need to get headers, can this at least be made as compact as possible?  Or let me do just 100 at a time?

Alternatively, I've tried to delete an entire folder via email client UI's, but this doesn't seem to work.  I think it's trying to move all the headers to the trash first, and fails at that, so never gets to the expunge part.  So I'm not sure that deleting a folder is actually more efficient than deleting its contents.

Any thoughts appreciated.  I usually work in Java or Python, but I'm flexible.  I think this is a protocol issue, not a library issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're not using an atypical server (like gmail which is quite atypical) you can do these commands, after LOGIN, and SELECT [folder]:

```
A001 STORE 1:N +FLAGS (\Deleted)
A002 EXPUNGE
A003 STORE 1:N +FLAGS (\Deleted)
A004 EXPUNGE
```

And so on, where you replace N with your batch size.  This will not use the trash folder (unless your IMAP server has special logic, like Gmail: for gmail, tweak your IMAP access settings).

You should be able to do this:

```
A001 STORE 1:* +FLAGS (\Deleted)
A002 EXPUNGE
```

That may take a while though.

In fact, you can use a tool like [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) to login and speak the protocol yourself:

```
socat READLINE: OPENSSL:[server]:993,noverify,crlf
a LOGIN [user] "[password]"
b SELECT [folder]
```

And then the store and expunge commands from above.

Answer (score 0):

The [IMAP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) provides a [`DELETE` command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.3.4) that can destroy an entire mailbox.

Comment: Thanks @sarnold good info, BUT I'm not sure that fixes it. Let's say "junk_folder" has 100,000 messages in it, and I use the DELETE command. I suspect this will be problematic for many implementations. From what I've seen, I think the IMAP server will start 100,000 copy commands to Trash, and set the deleted flag on the original 100,000 messages, so you'd now have 200,000 messages and be more over-quota for a while. Only when all that is done will it do the expunge and reclaim the space, and is likely to choke instead. Thoughts?? (Depends on the implementation of course)

Comment: Unless your implementation is particularly broken, DELETE [folder] should not cause all messages to be moved to trash.  "Trash" folders are not part of the specification, and are mostly just a gentleman's contract by clients.  Google is an exception: they do a lot of work in the background, but you can change the settings to delete right away.

Comment: @Max: Thanks for the additional details.